# Arcpy remove invalid character

Tags: python, arcpy, modelbuilder

I've built a model that takes the name of the Excel worksheet containing xy data, and uses that name as the name of the output shapefile. ( Worksheet "massachusetts_sightings" in an xlsx becomes "massachusetts_sightings$.shp"). I do this using Parse Path. Notice that a "$" is added.

If I then feed this shapefile, massachusetts_sightings$.shp into a clip tool (say, to clip out points in the data that are not in my study area), I get an error for an invalid character in the clip tool. My suspicion is the $. I know I could remove this with Calculate Value...but I can't figure out the code block.

My parse path output is called Value:

[image: Codeblock]

Can someone help troubleshoot? I haven't used Python in years-

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Scratch"
arcpy.env.workspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Data"

# Script arguments
XY_Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

Define_Coordinate_System = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

Projection = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

Geographic_Transformation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

Study_Area = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

Projected_and_Clipped_Data = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
if Projected_and_Clipped_Data == '#' or not Projected_and_Clipped_Data:
    Projected_and_Clipped_Data = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Data\\%fixed%_Clip.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
xy_event = XY_Table
v_defined = xy_event
defined_data = v_defined
v_projected = defined_data
Value = XY_Table

# Process: Parse Path
arcpy.ParsePath_mb(XY_Table, "NAME")

# Process: Make XY Event Layer
tempEnvironment0 = gp.scratchWorkspace
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Scratch"
tempEnvironment1 = gp.workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Data"
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(XY_Table, "", "", xy_event, "", "")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tempEnvironment0
arcpy.env.workspace = tempEnvironment1

# Process: Copy Features
tempEnvironment0 = gp.scratchWorkspace
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Scratch"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(xy_event, v_defined, "", "0", "0", "0")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tempEnvironment0

# Process: Define Projection
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(v_defined, Define_Coordinate_System)

# Process: Project
tempEnvironment0 = gp.scratchWorkspace
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Scratch"
tempEnvironment1 = gp.workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Data"
arcpy.Project_management(defined_data, v_projected, Projection, Geographic_Transformation, "")
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tempEnvironment0
arcpy.env.workspace = tempEnvironment1

# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis(v_projected, Study_Area, Projected_and_Clipped_Data, "")

# Process: Calculate Value
arcpy.CalculateValue_management("\"%Value%\".strip(\"$\")", "\\n", "String")
```

Comment: One mistake is reassigning the name of the function (GetName) as a variable. Your function simply needs one statement, saying "return os.path.dirname(input)" and that's all.

Comment: Michalis, thank you for taking the time; I was't able to get your suggestion to work. However...it appears my script is working (i admit, i could've been better written), but files are still being created, but they are named "1_Clip" (the clip should be there, but the 1 replaces the worksheet name). It looks like I'm missing something still.

Comment: without more of the code it is hard to figure out what is wrong. Perhaps edit your question to get more attention too.

Answer (score 5):

Happily in Python (arcpy) getting rid of this character is a simple one line expression, and so you don't need to use the entire code block; instead in the Expression you should just be able to use [str.strip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

```py
"%Value%".strip("$")
```

Note the code block doesn't need to set output, just needs to return, and you only need to import os if you want the basename. So your expression could be:

```
strip_chars("%Value%")
```

And the code block:

```
import os.path
def strip_chars(s):
    return os.path.basename(s).strip("$")
```

Note that the value insertion only works in Model Builder, not within Python itself. Instead you can use [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to get the result you're after, for example (note the `%s`):

```
fixed = "some_filename"
Projected_and_Clipped_Data = "X:\\Tools\\XY\\point_upload\\Data\\%s_Clip.shp" % fixed
```

Comment: I continue to get the same answer, no matter what code block / expression I use, the number 1. I've used the provided expressions/code blocks, all giving no matter what code I use, all I get is the 1 as my file name. Perhaps I'm using the inline variable wrong. If I use "%Value%".strip("$") as my expression, and then rename the green output circle as fixed, or as outputvalue, and then in the Clip tool, I write either %fixed%_clip, %Value%_clip, or %outputvalue%_clip, I get "1_clip.shp" as the output.

Comment: @MBarretts20 Edited my answer above to say that the value insertion only works from within model builder. If you're just running it from a script you should assign the variable in the script and use String Formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Solved- 
I needed to move the parse path / calculate value to the first step in the model- not the last, as I had originally. I believe the expressions/codes above will work, but were not the final ones used. But a huge thank you to those who took time to weigh in. Most appreciated. 
[image]