# Remove Illegal Characters in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, modelbuilder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arcpy remove invalid character](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35099/arcpy-remove-invalid-character)

I've created a model that iterates through a shape file and pulls out unique values in a field.  These unique values are then used to create new shapefiles with the name of the shapefile being the unique value.  The problem is I have illegal characters (such as "-") in the unique values.  How can I strip these out before the shapefile is made?

Here's the python:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")

# Script arguments
Inc_Birds2_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Inc_Birds2_shp == '#' or not Inc_Birds2_shp:
Inc_Birds2_shp = "C:\\Users\\OJB\\Desktop\\BurdsGIS\\Peru\\GIS\\Created\\Inc_Birds2.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
v_Output_Values_ = Inc_Birds2_shp
v_Val__shp = v_Output_Values_
Val = Inc_Birds2_shp
Testing = "C:\\Users\\OJB\\Desktop\\BurdsGIS\\Peru\\GIS\\Created\\Testing"

# Process: Iterate Feature Selection
arcpy.IterateFeatureSelection_mb(Inc_Birds2_shp, "Com_Name #", "false")

# Process: Feature Class to Feature Class
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(v_Output_Values_, Testing,
```

I'm new to python and prefer working in Model Builder, but I think there is a strip function somewhere.  I'm guessing I need to strip the illegal characters out of v_Output_Values_

Any help appreciated

Comment: Might also want to look into this tool by Dan Patterson: [Split Layer By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808)

Comment: Thanks blah, the rewritten script for 10 works well.  I could only find the 9.3 version yesterday and was having difficulty rewriting it for 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strip doesn't quite work like that - it only strips from the beginning and/or end of the string. Perhaps the replace method will work for you. Here's an example.

```
>>> str01 = "alpha-beta"
>>> str02 = str01.replace('-','_')
>>> str02
alpha_beta
```

(The >>> are meant to represent prompts in your interpreter, if that wasn't clear.)

Comment: You could also put the Python code into a Calculate Field tool if you want to perform the operation in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Calculate Value*